# How to disable jQuery accordion open on Enter keypress?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery accordion like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Log Output</h3>                             
    <div id="result" class="logStyle"  />
</div>
```

I init it in my javascript like this (in the document ready function):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 
    header: "h3", 
    collapsible: true, 
    active: false
});
```

I'm trying to prevent my one item from opening when the user hits 'Enter'.  I've tried removing the keypress:

```
$("#accordion").removeAttr("keypress");
```

Handling the event directly:

```
$("#accordion").bind('keypress', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}});
```

and

```
$("#accordion").keypress(function (evt) {
    var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode  == 13) { 
        return false;
    }
});
```

But no matter what I do, hitting enter opens the accordion.  How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#accordion').unbind('accordion');
```

Better use `.on()` and `.off()`, 'cause you're able to delegate events with this functions, too. :)

http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the on/off thing (jQuery n00b)- I tried using the unbind and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see, that you keypress-event should be bind to the document. Try this: $(document).on('keypress', function(evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode === 13) {
        $('#accordion').unbind('accordion');
    }
});

on and off are really easy to handle. Just look at the given examples (I'm using on in my example in this comment, too.)

Comment: I'm doing something wrong.  I added exactly that code to the document ready function, and no change.  I have (outside the document ready function) a $(document).keypress(function(e)) { if (e.keyCode == '13) { // do stuff }});  and that works just fine... I just cant seem to prevent the accordion to opening on 'Enter'

Comment: It has something to do with that other method- if I comment it out your code works.  Hmmm. I need 'Enter' to work on the document, but not on the accordion.

Comment: Just for me to proof if I really got what you want to do: I read your post 3 times again and I'm not sure...at which events do you want to get your accordion-event to be fired?

Comment: Didn't you remove your old keypress-event?

Comment: I tried a couple of things- adding the unbind line to my existing document keypress handler which didnt work.  Then I commented my document keypress handler out and the accordion behaved perfectly.  So somehow the keypress to handle enter on the document is preventing the code you posted to work.

Comment: So I ended up circumventing the accordion- I tried the JQWidgets expander and it did what I wanted- bummed I didn't find a way around this, but at least there was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using `$("#accordion")` try `$(document)`

Comment: I need the keypress on the document :(